# Creating a schema for a nested Pyspark object

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm attempting to create some sample data frames to put test against some functions, regularly I get JSON objects with nested objects(arrays or more JSON objects), I need to test these for differing types, namely `Struct` and `Array` and pass them to a correct function based on their type to create a tabular dataframe.

These objects are from APIs some internal, some external so I'm at the mercy of app developers.

Let's assume I want to create a table as follows to test against:

```
+----+------+------------------------------+
|    |   id | arr                          |
|----+------+------------------------------|
|  0 |    1 | [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]] |
|  1 |    2 | [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]       |
+----+------+------------------------------+
```

My assumption would be I would need to create a schema as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField,StructType,StringType,IntegerType,ArrayType

schema = StructType([
  StructField('id', IntegerType(),True),
  StructField('arr', ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType(),True),True),True)
  
])


data = [ [1,2], #< id.
 [[ [0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7]], # < arr
        [[1,2,3,],[4,5,6]]] 
]


df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)
```

which returns a `TypeError`:

```
field arr: ArrayType(IntegerType,true) can not accept object 2 in type <class 'int'>
```

Where have I made an error?

When all is said and done this the output I will get when I've passed these through a recursive function:

```
+----+------+-------+
|    |   id |   arr |
|----+------+-------|
|  0 |    1 |     0 |
|  0 |    1 |     1 |
|  0 |    1 |     2 |
|  0 |    1 |     3 |
|  0 |    1 |     4 |
|  0 |    1 |     5 |
|  0 |    1 |     6 |
|  0 |    1 |     7 |
|  1 |    2 |     1 |
|  1 |    2 |     2 |
|  1 |    2 |     3 |
|  1 |    2 |     4 |
|  1 |    2 |     5 |
|  1 |    2 |     6 |
+----+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list `data` should contain a list of rows, instead of a list of columns.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField,StructType,StringType,IntegerType,ArrayType

schema = StructType([
  StructField('id', IntegerType(),True),
  StructField('arr', ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType(),True),True),True)
])

data = [
    [1, [[0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7]] ],
    [2, [[1,2,3,],[4,5,6]] ]
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)

df.show(truncate=False)
+---+----------------------------+
|id |arr                         |
+---+----------------------------+
|1  |[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]|
|2  |[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]      |
+---+----------------------------+
```

For exploding the arrays you can do this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn('arr', F.explode(F.flatten('arr'))).show()
+---+---+
| id|arr|
+---+---+
|  1|  0|
|  1|  1|
|  1|  2|
|  1|  3|
|  1|  4|
|  1|  5|
|  1|  6|
|  1|  7|
|  2|  1|
|  2|  2|
|  2|  3|
|  2|  4|
|  2|  5|
|  2|  6|
+---+---+
```